# How to convert Linq to SQLCommand

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sqlcommand

I have SQLCommand below but instead of writing SQL text inside method I would like to write entire SQL command in Linq to prevent Entities mismatch if POCO models are changed.

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [Order] SET [Credits] = @Credits WHERE [Id] = @Id",
                        new SqlParameter("Credits", remainingCredits),
                        new SqlParameter("Id", order.Id));
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I think his problem is pretty clear

Comment: @E.Vaughan actually it fails the first step of ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as it shows no attempt at researching the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var context= new DbContext())
{
    var order = context.Orders.Where(x=>x.Id==Id).SingleOrDefault();
    if(!order)
        order.Credits = remainingCredits

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In order to be more specific, I should know the version of entity framework you use. However the general idea is the above.